# Are there any OR challenges that are similar to Kaggle's competitions?

Tags: online-resources, applications

I am looking for previous OR challenges.

My goal is :

1. Applying my knowledge while solving problems suggested in those competitions; and/or
2. If possible, reading solutions posted by participants.

I learned a lot about machine learning (ML) by reading solutions to [Kaggle competitions](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions). I couldn't find any similar website for OR problems. It seems that the ML hype is eating up everything.

Comment: I am [tracking OR challenges in this dedicated twitter account](https://twitter.com/ORChallenges).

Answer (score 28):

The *Helmut Schmidt Universitat* contains a list of past, ongoing, and future contests in Operations Research.

> https://www.hsu-hh.de/logistik/research/challenges

For example:

- Active challenges: [ITC 2019](https://www.itc2019.org/home#overview) on finding feasible solutions for organising student rooms and times.
- Past challenges: [PACE 2018](https://pacechallenge.wordpress.com/pace-2018/) on Steiner trees on an undirected edge-weighted graph

They are a considerable number of links to past events, though some of them have already been introduced in other answers, such as ROADEF.

Answer (score 20):

I personally like [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/). This website has mathematical problems that usually require programming to solve them. If you solve a problem you get access to the corresponding problem forum, in which users post their code and discuss their approaches.

Admittedly, I consider Project Euler to be more about mathematics and computer science than about Operations Research. Still, there are plenty of problems that involve optimization, or to which OR techniques can be applied.

I suggest the following problems for those with OR skills. Whether these problems are really OR is of course debatable, and the list is non-exhaustive: Problem [11](https://projecteuler.net/problem=11), [18](https://projecteuler.net/problem=18), [67](https://projecteuler.net/problem=67), [68](https://projecteuler.net/problem=68), [81](https://projecteuler.net/problem=81), [82](https://projecteuler.net/problem=82), [83](https://projecteuler.net/problem=83), [84](https://projecteuler.net/problem=84), [96](https://projecteuler.net/problem=96), [122](https://projecteuler.net/problem=122), [149](https://projecteuler.net/problem=149), [185](https://projecteuler.net/problem=185), [190](https://projecteuler.net/problem=190), [280](https://projecteuler.net/problem=280), [345](https://projecteuler.net/problem=345), [392](https://projecteuler.net/problem=392), [460](https://projecteuler.net/problem=460), and [607](https://projecteuler.net/problem=607).

Answer (score 16):

The French OR society has some interesting OR challenges

http://www.roadef.org/challenge/2018/en/index.php

Answer (score 16):

[Google Hashcode](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/hashcode) had some optimization challenges in the past. Problem definitions and data from previous years can be found [here](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/hashcode/archive).

Answer (score 15):

There is a [competition section](http://coral.ie.lehigh.edu/~mopta/competition) held during [MOPTA](http://coral.ie.lehigh.edu/~mopta/) (Modeling and Optimization: Theory and Applications), which is organized annually by Lehigh University. The competition is for students only and usually devoted to a practical problem and sponsored by a solver company.

Answer (score 15):

And we also have the [DIMACS implementation challenges](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/programs/challenge/)  #ofcourse

Answer (score 14):

For constraint programming, there's the [Minizinc Challenge](https://www.minizinc.org/challenge.html).

Comment: And the xcsp3 challenge as well.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a link to INFORMS OR and analytics students team competition. You can also find the challenges for previous years and the presentations of the winner team. I believe you need to be registered in INFORMS in order to get the data.

https://connect.informs.org/oratc/home

Edit: in [The Operation Research Challenge](http://orchallenge.org/) (TORCH)'s website, you can find the challenges and required data as well.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find how to download the data sets, there are only problems' statements and solutions' presentations.

Answer (score 12):

**Simulation**
The simulation-software company [Simio](https://www.simio.com/index.php) holds an annual [student competition](https://www.simio.com/academics/student-competition.php).
[Arena](https://www.arenasimulation.com/) has [one also](https://www.arenasimulation.com/academic/iie-arena-student-competition).

**Forecasting**
There are the [Makridakis Competitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makridakis_Competitions), though they are infrequent. **M-4** is just now getting finalized.

**Optimization**
List of [active & historical competitions](https://www.hsu-hh.de/logistik/research/challenges). ([as mentioned](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/1308/491))
[Grid Optimization competition](https://gocompetition.energy.gov/challenges).
[Black Box Optimization competition](https://bbcomp.ini.rub.de/).

Answer (score 4):

**Mathematical Contest in Modeling (MCM)**

Mathematical Contest in Modeling (MCM), an international contest for high school students and college undergraduates. It challenges teams of students to clarify, analyze, and propose solutions to open-ended problems. The contest attracts diverse students and faculty advisors from over 900 institutions around the world.

LINK - [MCM](https://www.comap.com/undergraduate/contests/matrix/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

**Global Trajectory Optimization**

Mission level Trajectory Optimization is also subfield of OR, although it is often only worked on by the aerospace industry. The Global Trajectory Optimization Competition is a competition between aerospace engineers and mathematicians world wide which work to the best solution to "nearly-impossible" problems of interplanetary trajectory design.

Since the next years workshop is hosted by the winners of the last years one, the solutions and problems are hosted at different websites. However [the GTOC portal by
ESA has links to all of those](https://sophia.estec.esa.int/gtoc_portal/).

Answer (score 3):

Let me also mention the [IBM Research Ponder This challenge](https://medium.com/ibm-data-ai/4-figures-3-numbers-and-some-thoughts-about-ibm-cplex-and-ibm-research-ponder-this-7ecee7260c5b).
Not always OR oriented but I have solved 50+ of those with an OR Tool : OPL CPLEX.

The Decision Management Community also offers some [OR challenges](https://dmcommunity.org/challenge/).