Operations research contests \ hackathons
Are there any contests \ hackathons in the field of operations research, supply chain and logistics, operations management or fields closely adjacent to these areas happening in 2024?

Related question https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1304/are-there-any-or-challenges-that-are-similar-to-kaggles-competitions

I used to track them on this Twitter account.
And Martin used to track them on this website.
Both are unmaintained.
For what it's worth, many competitions are yearly or x-yearly such as:

Kaggle Santa competitions
Verolog
ROADEF challenges
International (Nurse|Timetabling) Competition

